# value error happens when using GridSearchCV

Tags: python, classification, svm

I am using GridSearchCV to do classification and my codes are:

```
parameter_grid_SVM = {'dual':[True,False],
                    'loss':["squared_hinge","hinge"],
                    'penalty':["l1","l2"] 
                    }
clf = GridSearchCV(LinearSVC(),param_grid=parameter_grid_SVM,verbose=2)
clf.fit(trian_data, labels)
```

And then, I meet the error

ValueError: Unsupported set of arguments: penalty='l1' is only supported when dual='false'., Parameters: penalty='l1', loss='hinge', dual=False

later on I change my code to :

```
clf = GridSearchCV(LinearSVC(penalty='l1',dual=False),verbose=2)
```

And I meet the error

TypeError: **init**() takes at least 3 arguments (3 given)

I also tried:

```
parameter_grid_SVM = {
                    'loss':["squared_hinge"]
                    }
clf = GridSearchCV(LinearSVC(penalty='l1',dual=False),param_grid=parameter_grid_SVM,verbose=2)
clf.fit(trian_data, labels)
```

However, I still have the error

ValueError: Unsupported set of arguments: penalty='l1' is only supported when dual='false'., Parameters: penalty='l1', loss='squared_hinge', dual=False

Anyone has idea what I should do to deal with that?

Comment: Just a hunch: try adding the fixed parameters to the dictionary you are using for the grid search as singleton lists: 'penalty': ['l1'], 'dual': [False].

Comment: I tried this also, but it returns the error ValueError: Unsupported set of arguments: penalty='l1' is only supported when dual='false'., Parameters: penalty='l1', loss='squared_hinge', dual=False

Answer (score 2):

I also met this problem when doing sparse SVM. I find one piece of working demo code in this page [SVM module explanation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/svm.html). Hope it might help.

`clf = LinearSVC(loss='l2', penalty='l1', dual=False)`

Answer (score 2):

One option is to instruct `GridSearchCV` to set the score manually if model throws an exception using the `error_score` parameter. See [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43009566/skip-forbidden-parameter-combinations-when-using-gridsearchcv/43010440#43010440).

Answer (score 2):

Had a similar issue and in my case, it was writing twelve `12` instead of 'el two' `l2` in some instances.

Answer (score 0):

The code that produces this error message is [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/74861d023efb27ec2147ef1cc0b51ec44b487093/sklearn/svm/base.py#L632). I don't see what would cause this to only happen occasionally, but the bare else means that presumably it's something else other than just the penalty='l1', dual='false' combination.