# Skip forbidden parameter combinations when using GridSearchCV

Tags: python, optimization, scikit-learn, grid-search, svc

I want to greedily search the entire parameter space of my support vector classifier using [GridSearchCV](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html). However, some combinations of parameters are forbidden by [LinearSVC](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.LinearSVC.html) and [throw an exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29902190/value-error-happens-when-using-gridsearchcv). In particular, there are mutually exclusive combinations of the `dual`, `penalty`, and `loss` parameters:

For example, this code:

```
from sklearn import svm, datasets
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV

iris = datasets.load_iris()
parameters = {'dual':[True, False], 'penalty' : ['l1', 'l2'], \
              'loss': ['hinge', 'squared_hinge']}
svc = svm.LinearSVC()
clf = GridSearchCV(svc, parameters)
clf.fit(iris.data, iris.target)
```

Returns `ValueError: Unsupported set of arguments: The combination of penalty='l2' and loss='hinge' are not supported when dual=False, Parameters: penalty='l2', loss='hinge', dual=False`

My question is: is it possible to make GridSearchCV skip combinations of parameters which the model forbids? If not, is there an easy way to construct a parameter space which won't violate the rules?

Comment: This would still be a problem, but a lesser problem, if we could at least suppress the FitFailedWarning statements in this case.  I face the same battle where I know some combinations are illegal but the logic (as explained below) to prevent these combinations is way too ugly.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I solved this problem by passing `error_score=0.0` to `GridSearchCV`:

> error_score : ‘raise’ (default) or numeric
>
> Value to assign to the
> score if an error occurs in estimator fitting. If set to ‘raise’, the
> error is raised. If a numeric value is given, FitFailedWarning is
> raised. This parameter does not affect the refit step, which will
> always raise the error.

UPDATE: newer versions of sklearn print out a bunch of `ConvergenceWarning` and `FitFailedWarning`. I had a hard time surppressing them with `contextlib.suppress`, but [there is a hack around that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53784971/how-to-disable-convergencewarning-using-sklearn#comment111678231_56781741) involving a testing context manager:

```py
from sklearn import svm, datasets 
from sklearn.utils._testing import ignore_warnings 
from sklearn.exceptions import FitFailedWarning, ConvergenceWarning 
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV 

with ignore_warnings(category=[ConvergenceWarning, FitFailedWarning]): 
    iris = datasets.load_iris() 
    parameters = {'dual':[True, False], 'penalty' : ['l1', 'l2'], \ 
                 'loss': ['hinge', 'squared_hinge']} 
    svc = svm.LinearSVC() 
    clf = GridSearchCV(svc, parameters, error_score=0.0) 
    clf.fit(iris.data, iris.target)
```

Comment: Is there a workaround to actually avoid these combinations (or any other) before they actually output any error?

Comment: @Khabz my answer was too big to fit in the comments, so I posted it as another answer.

Comment: @crypdick is there a way to avoid seeing FitFailedWarning in the outcome?

Comment: @Nihat I edited my answer to suppress the new warnings

Answer (score 5):

If you want to completely avoid exploring specific combinations (without waiting to run into errors), you have to construct the grid yourself. GridSearchCV can take a list of dicts, where the grids spanned by each dictionary in the list are explored.

In this case, the conditional logic was not so bad, but it would be really tedious for something more complicated:

```
from sklearn import svm, datasets
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from itertools import product

iris = datasets.load_iris()

duals = [True, False]
penaltys = ['l1', 'l2']
losses = ['hinge', 'squared_hinge']
all_params = list(product(duals, penaltys, losses))
filtered_params = [{'dual': [dual], 'penalty' : [penalty], 'loss': [loss]}
                   for dual, penalty, loss in all_params
                   if not (penalty == 'l1' and loss == 'hinge') 
                   and not ((penalty == 'l1' and loss == 'squared_hinge' and dual is True))
                  and not ((penalty == 'l2' and loss == 'hinge' and dual is False))]

svc = svm.LinearSVC()
clf = GridSearchCV(svc, filtered_params)
clf.fit(iris.data, iris.target)
```

Comment: I appreciate your effort but this seems like a slightly sketchy solution which would result in alot of verbose for a problem with a big number of restrictions

Comment: @Khabz agreed, this code is cursed! If there's a bazillion conditionals, one possibility is to programmatically construct the list of conditionals in `filtered_params`, then `str.join(conditionals_list)`, and finally `eval()` the string to do the list comprehension.