# Avoid certain parameter combinations in GridSearchCV

Tags: python, machine-learning, parameters, scikit-learn, grid-search

I'm using scikit-learn's `GridSearchCV` to iterate over a parameter space to tune a model. Specifically, I'm using it to test different hyperparameters in a neural network. The grid is as follows:

```
params = {'num_hidden_layers': [0,1,2],
          'hidden_layer_size': [64,128,256],
          'activation': ['sigmoid', 'relu', 'tanh']}
```

The problem is that I end up running redundant models when hidden `num_hidden_layers` is set to `0`. It will run a model with 0 hidden layers and 64 units, another with 128 units, and another with 256 units. All of these models are equivalent since there is no hidden layer. This is highly inefficient and it means I need to write more code to remove redundancy in the results.

Is there a way to prevent such parameter combinations, perhaps by passing a tuple of parameters?

Comment: I should add that this problem is distinct from that mentioned here, where the user wants to skip "forbidden" combinations that will generate errors: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43009566/skip-forbidden-parameter-combinations-when-using-gridsearchcv

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[GridSearchCV](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html) allows you to pass list of dictionaries to params:

> param_grid : dict or list of dictionaries
>
> Dictionary with parameters names (string) as keys and lists of
>   parameter settings to try as values, or a list of such dictionaries,
>   in which case the grids spanned by each dictionary in the list are
>   explored. This enables searching over any sequence of parameter
>   settings.

So you can specify these dictionaries to be certain subdictionaries of your original dictionary. Thus, you could avoid irrelevant combinations.

Answer (score 31):

The [sklearn documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/grid_search.html#exhaustive-grid-search) suggests two parameter grids.

So you could do something like this:

```
param_grid = [
    {'num_hidden_layers': [1,2],
      'hidden_layer_size': [64,128,256],
      'activation': ['sigmoid', 'relu', 'tanh']},
    {'num_hidden_layers': [0],
      'hidden_layer_size': [64],
      'activation': ['sigmoid', 'relu', 'tanh']}
    ]
```