# How to include TransformedTargetRegressor parameters as parameters for GridSearch?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I want to perform a GridSearch with my feature engineering and model hyper-parameters. I want to include in the GridSearch, whether transforming the target variable improves accuracy. I found a way to do that, by passing in the `TransformedTargetRegressor` parameters to the grid search, with the parameters being a function and then a custom identity function I defined.

This predictably produces a bunch of errors though, as in completing the GridSearch, `TransformedTargetRegressor` will take the combination of no-transformation (identity) and then an inverse transformation of the exponential function.

Is there a way to pass in pairs of hyper-parameters to the grid search, e.g. `[(identity_, identity), (np.log1p, np.expm1)]`?

I have reviewed the scikit-learn docs and googled around, but I can't find an example of using the transformed target regressor in a grid search pipeline. Is this not common practice? Is there a reason to avoid doing this?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.compose import TransformedTargetRegressor
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

def identity_(x):
    return x

X_train = pd.DataFrame(pd.Series([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]))
y_train = pd.Series([5, 6, 7, 8, 7, 8, 9])

search_params_ = {
    'model__func': [np.log1p, identity_],
    'model__inverse_func': [np.expm1, identity_]
}

pipeline_ = Pipeline([
    ('scaler', StandardScaler()),
    ('model', TransformedTargetRegressor(regressor=LinearRegression(), check_inverse=False))
])


reg_search_cv = GridSearchCV(pipeline_, search_params_)

reg_search_cv.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Comment: As in [this question and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45352420/avoid-certain-parameter-combinations-in-gridsearchcv) you could pass in a list of dictionaries rather than a single dictionary, each dict containing only the parameters that should be paired

Comment: Thank you! The linked solution solved my problem.

Comment: Close as duplicate [Avoid certain parameter combinations in GridSearchCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45352420/avoid-certain-parameter-combinations-in-gridsearchcv)